# Regex evaluate to true but its not supposed to

Tags: javascript, regex

I have input field which db is expecting to come as integer. if i type `60` it works fine, but `60.00` doesn't. I did `RegExp` for validation with the `^[0-9]+/` expession. It works fine for inputs like `60.asdass`, `60.0320320`, `dasdasdas.60` etc. but if i type `60.` and it evaluates to true and it passes the validation and i get an error from db. How can i make my `regex` to sets as false in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the end of string anchor (`$`):

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill accept it in 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. By using anchors it will fail if the full input is not the regular expression specified.

```
^\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the rest of the array as well and use start and end of the string as well for testing.

```js
function check() {
    var element =document.getElementById('input'),
        value = element.value;
    
    element.style.color = /^\d+(\.\d+)*$/.test(value) ? '#000000': '#ff0000';
}
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" onkeyup="check()">
```